# Junit Test case for a parameterized Java class with Requests going to 3rd Party End Point

Tags: java, junit, parameter-passing, code-coverage

I have a java class SendRequest.java which has the following methods

```
public class SendRequest implements Transformer {

public Document transform(Document xmlToTransform,
            Map<String, Object> parameters, String script) {
-- Create connection to third party
-- Create the payload request to be sent
-- Send the request to third party
-- Fetch the response from third party
-- Depending on the status code returned return either the success or error response

}
```

The above method in turn makes method calls to create successResponse or, errorResponse.

The Junit Test case I created is not covering the Java code, and ending up with hardly 50% code coverage. The challenge is to mock up the service and identify the parameterized input values.

Junit

```
SendRequest sendRequest= new SendRequest();
Document xmlResponse = sendRequest.transform(xmlToTransform, parameters, script);

-- xmlToTransform is the input request in xml format.
```

Is there a way to mock up a class call i.e. not send the request to the third party service rather just receive the request and proceed through the code?

Answer (score 0):

We need to mock the `class` methods that is sending the request to third party API, e.g. if you are using `RestTemplate` then you can do something like this:

```
@Mock
protected RestTemplate restTemplate;

ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
responseEntity.getBody().putAll(<sample response body>);
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), 
        Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), Mockito.any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

This example works if your class uses `RestTemplate.exchange()`. Similarly, you can mock the method of corresponding controller class.